# How to make a skin for vertices imported from python script?

Tags: python, vertices, faces

I have a script that generates points in the configuration that I need for a surface.

Here is the code that I'm using to generate the vertices.

```
def add_vertices(self, lat, lon, alt, max_range, azimuth, az_halfangle, min_el, max_el):
    verts = stationary_sector_vertices(lat, lon, alt, max_range, azimuth, az_halfangle, min_el, max_el)
    initialPos = CC.geodetic2ecef(lat,lon,alt).values
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('mesh')
    myobj = bpy.data.objects.new('myobj',mesh)
    myobj.location = initialPos[0,:]
    mesh.from_pydata( verts-initialPos[0,:], [],[] )
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(myobj)
```

CC.geodetic2ecef is a coordinate converter that I wrote.

stationary_sector_vertices is the code that generates these vertices.

Unfortunately I dont know how to tell blender how to create faces over these vertices.

Is there a nice way to do this in code?

I understand that the definition of the surface can be somewhat ambiguous, however, in this particular case, I just want the surface to be this spherical wedge.  If more information is needed, I'd be happy to try and supply it.

Images below:

Random View
[image: Random View]

Top View
[image: Top View]